# How to access selector in foreach statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have two ajax calls that fire when a user clicks a date on `jquery datepicker`.

On the second ajax call I want it to populate the response/data to a paragraph `tag class="spots"` in the first ajax call to show available spots for that specific time.

My problem is the second ajax call only populates & repeats the first result it finds. I think it's because my class selector is the same in the foreach row. I've set an `id + item.id` to make them dynamic, but how do I access them in my `jquery` selector? Any help would be appreciated. See code below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

//show datpicker calendar set getDay function on select
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    onSelect: getDay,

});

 function getDay() {

 var date1 = $('#datepicker').datepicker('getDate');
 var day = date1.getDay();

//set hidden input to numberical value of day
    $('#dayOfWeek').val(day);   
//set hidden textbox value near datepicker to submit date in proper format for db
    $('#date').val($.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date1));  



//ajax form the get available times to play
$.ajax({
  url: $('#form').attr('action'),
  type: 'POST',
  data : $('#form').serialize(),
     success: function(response){

     //clear results before showing another date selected
      $('.table').html("");

      //loop through json results and build table
      $.each(JSON.parse(response), function(i, item) {
          var jdate = $('#date').val();
          var id = item.id;


        $('<tr>').html("<td>" + item.time + "</td><td>"  + '<input type="text" name="jtime" value="' + item.time + '"' + "/>"  + '<input type="text" name="jdate" value="' + jdate + '"' + ">"  + "Spots:" + '<p class="spots" id="spots_' + id + '"'+ ">" + '</p>'  + "</td>").appendTo('#availableTimes');

        });//end loop 

            //fire getSpots function
            getSpots();     

  }//end success
});
return false;

};   //end getDay function

//  get available spots
function getSpots(){

var values = {
        'jtime': $('input[name="jtime"]').val(),
        'jdate': $('input[name="jdate"]').val(),
};

$.ajax({
  //url: form.attr('action'),
 url: '/reservations/getSpots',
  type: 'POST',
 // data : form.serialize(),
 data : values,
      success: function(response){

        $('.spots').html(response);

      }//end success


    }); //end ajax
   return false;

};//end getSpots function


    })//end doc ready            



             </script>
```

Here is a snippet of code that works but it uses a form with a button to submit the second ajax call. I want it to work like this without the button submit. Want the second ajax call to post when the datapicker date is selected. Maybe i'm thinking about this wrong.

```
//show datpicker calendar set getDay function on select
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    onSelect: getDay
});


})//end doc ready
 function getDay() {

 var date1 = $('#datepicker').datepicker('getDate');
 var day = date1.getDay();

//set hidden input to numberical value of day
    $('#dayOfWeek').val(day);   
//set hidden textbox value near datepicker to submit date in proper format for db
    $('#date').val($.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date1));  



//ajax form the get available times to play
$.ajax({
  url: $('#form').attr('action'),
  type: 'POST',
  data : $('#form').serialize(),
     success: function(response){

     //clear results before showing another date selected
      $('.table').html("");

      //loop through json results and build table
      $.each(JSON.parse(response), function(i, item) {
          var jdate = $('#date').val();
          var id = item.id;


        $('<tr>').html("<td>" + item.time + "</td><td>" + '<form  class="insideForm" action="/reservations/getSpots" accept-charset="utf-8"  method="">'  + '<input type="text" name="jtime" value="' + item.time + '"' + "/>"  + '<input type="text" name="jdate" value="' + jdate + '"' + ">" + '<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Spots">' + "Spots:" + '<p class="spots" id="spots_' + id + '"'+ ">" + '</p>' + '</form>' + "</td>").appendTo('#availableTimes');

        });//end loop 


        getSpots();


  }//end success
});
  return false;


};   //end getDay function



//  get available spots
function getSpots(){
            //ajax form the get available spots 


$('.insideForm').submit(function(){
var form = $(this).closest('form');

$.ajax({
  url: form.attr('action'),
  type: 'POST',
  data : form.serialize(),

      success: function(response){

        $('.spots', form).html(response);

      }//end success


    }); //end ajax
 return false;
}); //end submit 

};//end getSpots function
```

Comment: what do you expect `var values =` in `getSpots` will be?

Comment: Why don't you get day and spots in a single request?

Comment: Formatting your code neatly [is a desirable thing](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/10/why-coding-style-matters/) for both you and for us.

Comment: @KoshVery if i knew how i would. They are coming from two different php functions.

Comment: @JaromandaX should be the results of the data base query

Comment: what is the tag of the `.spots` element and how does the `getSpots` response look?

Comment: that's not an answer - do you expect `jtime` and `jdate` properties to be single values? because that's what they will be

Comment: @JaromandaX yes they will be single values. They will be numbers based on the total number of spots available calculated in php. Example 25 spots

Comment: @ztadic91 it is a number. Example: 25 Spots

Comment: so, you knowingly create multiple inputs with `name="jtime"` and `name="jdate"` - but only use the values from one of them for `getSpots` - which will, of course be the first one - and you wonder why it only uses the first values - and you update `$('.spots')` with this value - which updates ALL `.spots` - you'll need to call `getSpots` for every `spot`, individually, inside the `each` loop

Comment: `is there multiple` - well, i's **your code** that does a `$.each` - so, why are you asking **me** if there are multiple? and on Feb 1 2018 there a **12** ... that's more than **1** - so, yes, there are multiple

Comment: @JaromandaX okay. Yes i misunderstood when you said multiple. There are multiple when the foreach runs. Hence in my question why i said "I think it's because my class selector is the same in the foreach row." But i don't know how to access them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call getSpots once and expect all to be updated? What you need to do is call getSpots once for every row, passing in an id to getSpots, so getSpots can update the correct row using the correct inputs

see lines marked `// ****` for changes to your code

> A deleted answer had a better approach

```
function getDay() {
    var date1 = $('#datepicker').datepicker('getDate');
    var day = date1.getDay();
    //set hidden input to numberical value of day
    $('#dayOfWeek').val(day);
    //set hidden textbox value near datepicker to submit date in proper format for db
    $('#date').val($.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date1));
    //ajax form the get available times to play
    $.ajax({
        url: $('#form').attr('action'),
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('#form').serialize(),
        success: function (response) {
            //clear results before showing another date selected
            $('.table').html('');
            //loop through json results and build table
            $.each(JSON.parse(response), function (i, item) {
                var jdate = $('#date').val();
                var id = item.id;
                $('<tr>').html('<td>' + item.time + '</td><td>' + '<input type="text" name="jtime" value="' + item.time + '"' + '/>' + '<input type="text" name="jdate" value="' + jdate + '"' + '>' + 'Spots:' + '<p class="spots" id="spots_' + id + '"' + '>' + '</p>' + '</td>').appendTo('#availableTimes');
                // **** call getSpots for every row
                getSpots('#spots_'+id, item.time, jdate);
            }); //end loop 
        } //end success

    });
    return false;
}    //end getDay function
//  get available spots
// **** accept output id, jtime and jdate
function getSpots(id, jtime, jdate) {
    // get the inputs for the current id
    var values = {
        'jtime': jtime,
        'jdate': jdate,
    };
    $.ajax({
        //url: form.attr('action'),
        url: '/reservations/getSpots',
        type: 'POST',
        // data : form.serialize(),
        data: values,
        success: function (response) {
            // **** update the spots for current id
            $(id).html(response);
        } //end success

    }); //end ajax
    return false;
} //end getSpots function
```

Comment: hmm now i'm getting nothing for spots.

Comment: I updated my original question with some code that does work but with a form and submit button in the foreach. Basically i want it to work like that but instead fire when the datapicker is selected. Maybe that can help clarify my question :)

Comment: When you say you get nothing, what can you see in the requests made by getSpots? i.e. request parameters and response

Comment: If i console.log it i get the number 25 for each, but nothing on the div selector/page.  Which makes me think 2 things. 1.   the second ajax call isn't sending my post data/values to the end point(because the default number is 25) If i click on Feb 10, i know the first row should be 5.  second, the selector may not be catching the right id or something.

Comment: I just updated var values =   to 'jtime': $('input[name="jtime"]').val(),
        'jdate': $('input[name="jdate"]').val(), and it gave me the correct first number at least

Comment: check the developer tools networks tab to see what is sent and received for each request

Comment: okay gives me the number 5 on each request from getSpots. Which is the first record for Feb 10

Comment: right, and the request parameters, are they different or the same?

Comment: add `console.log(id);` above `var values =` - is the id different each time?

Comment: Sorry. Where are the request parameters found on the network tab?

Comment: depends on the browser I guess - could be labeled `params`

Comment: now `console.log(values)` after assigning it ... do they change?

Comment: i'm using chrome. i see request headers

Comment: i think i am looking at what you mean. Form data is the same for each request. jtime:10:00:00
jdate:2018-02-10

Comment: typo on my part, hang on - call to getSpots should be `getSpots('#spots_inputs_'+id);` - and you've changed var values to `var values = {
        'jtime': $(id + '>input[name="jtime"]').val(),
        'jdate': $(id + '>input[name="jdate"]').val(),
    };` - because with my typo, you should not have got anything in values (I forgot to mark those lines as changed too)

Comment: Oh, I see what crhome does ... shows the POST params at the bottom of "headers" - seems odd, but chrome will be chrome

Comment: Okay. i updated the typo. Do you want me to switch my var values=... back to yours?

Comment: well, they'll need to be, because otherwise you'll always get the first input's values only - also update the where it "writes" `.spots`

Comment: i get no from parameters using the var values = 'yours'

Comment: right ... see edit, there was a deleted answer that had a better approach, though was a bit wrong - check the code now

Comment: unexpected token error on  var values = {
        'jtime': jtime,
        'jdate': jdate,
    };

Comment: really ... my typos are bad today, clealry there's a missing `{` in `function getSpots(id, jtime, jdate)` ... surely you can see that ... I mean, it's not like I can test this code at all - please forgive the small typos and do try to debug them yourself

Comment: NP, I found it before you got back to me. I appreciate you taking the time. Let me check it now.

Comment: Sorry for my "harsh" tone :p

Comment: Wow. it works! Thank you so much. I've been working on this for many hours. Going down different rabbit holes only to come up with nothing. As you can tell, i'm not really a great JS developer. I do more with PHP, but thank you again. I truly do appreciate it. Now i have to look over your code changes and understand how it all worked. So i know for next time. Thanks again

Comment: the code changes are minimal - boils down to a) call getSpots for each spot, and b) make sure you get data for each spot, not the first spot every time